# Remove "where" clause in views 3

Tags: 7, views, location

I want to remove "where" clause for city and postal_code in the views query. I found an example online for D6. I tried to change it a bit but it's not working. The "where" clause is still there.
Below is my code. It was originally for D6.

```
function distsearch_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'search' && $view->current_display == 'page_3') {
    // Remove the exposed filter conditions from the WHERE clause (WHERE city = MyCityInput)
    // and remove the corresponding args that were passed via the exposed filters
    // This effectively turns the city and zip code exposed filters into just text fields
    // that get used in distprox_mini_exposed_filter_proximity();

    $city = $view->exposed_raw_input['city'];
    $zip = $view->exposed_raw_input['postal_code'];

    // Remove the city or zip arguments (from the exposed filters)
    foreach ($query->where[0]['args'] as $key => $arg) {
      if ($arg == $city || $arg == $zip) {
        unset($query->where[0]['args'][$key]);
      }
    }

    // Remove the corresponding WHERE clause additions
    foreach ($query->where[0]['clauses'] as $key => $clause) {
      if (strpos($clause, 'postal_code') !== FALSE || strpos($clause, 'city') !== FALSE) {
        unset($query->where[0]['clauses'][$key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a lot easier than I thought. I dsm the query and did it like below. Not sure it's the perfect way to do it but it's working.

```
function distprox_mini_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
//dsm($query);
  if ($view->name == 'search' && $view->current_display == 'page_3') 
    unset($query->where[1]['conditions'][0]);
    unset($query->where[1]['conditions'][1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Aside from the obvious "just remove it from the UI" that I assume is not a solution for you, at first glance this looks like the right way to do it.

Comment: I'm trying to create a search by city and zip that will return other towns and zip codes within the miles entered by user. I already changed to query to use longitude and latitude. If I leave the where clause for city and zip, the search result will be limited to that particular city and zip. I got the idea from this great tutorial http://agileadam.com/drupal-city-zip-proximity.

Comment: One caveat, in my case I noticed that if you unset a condition on a field where some fields are set with a value on the actual nodes and some aren't, the only ones that will show up after the unset are ones with set values - weird.

Comment: UPDATE: so if the filter you're trying to unset is a field present on a related entity.... you may want to remove the table too: unset  `->table_queue['table_name']`. Wish there was a nice helper function for this, though I get it's uncommon.